# Nuxt 3 + Vite fails to build because of fsevents.node

Tags: node.js, vite, nuxt3

After updating Nuxt to 3.4.2 and types/node to 18.15.13 I get the following error when trying to build:

npm run dev:

```
✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node

    node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.js:13:23:
      13 │ const Native = require("./fsevents.node");
         ╵                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


 ERROR  [unhandledRejection] Build failed with 1 error:                                                                                                     9:03:37 AM
node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.js:13:23: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node

  node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.js:13:23: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/fsevents/fsevents.node
  at failureErrorWithLog (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1636:15)
  at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1048:25
  at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1512:9
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This is the package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev2": "nuxt dev",
    "dev": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 nuxt dev --https --ssl-cert localhost.pem --ssl-key localhost-key.pem",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "vue-gtag-next": "^1.14.0",
    "vue-sound": "^0.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.1.96",
    "@storyblok/nuxt": "^5.3.4",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.11.1",
    "gsap": "^3.11.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

I tried cleaning cache and deleting node_modules but a fresh install did not solve this.

Comment: I found a solution for React that worked for nuxt: 

Add fsevents to your Vite optimizeDeps exclude: (In nuxt.config.ts)

  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] },

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75640753/vite-esbuild-error-no-loader-is-configured-for-node-files-node-modules-fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude fsevents from vite in your nuxt config.

```
//nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  //...
  
  vite: {
    //...
    optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] },
  }
})
```

I can confirm @Jonathan's comment works.
Posting it as an answer to make it clear for future readers. Thanks Jonathan!